# XPage oneuiApplication: dynamic Configuration

Tags: configuration, xpages

I create custom control for application layout (cc_layout - ). The placeBar="false" in this control.
Is it possible to enable placeBar in XPage on the basis of some criteria. Example: Need only on data feeding form.

-MAK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a propertie definition (e.g.: name: placeBar, type: boolean) to your cc_layout see [LINK](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/09082009095808AMWEBJDV.htm) .Then you can pass the placebar propertie through to the 'underlying' Xpage where you place your layout.

In your cc_layout then add `placeBar="#{javascript:compositeData.placeBar;}"` to your application layout.